# Error in bidirectional breadth-first search

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble getting my bidirectional breadth-first search to work in Python.

Say I form a graph like the one [here](https://ibb.co/cDX2dJ).

If I run the bidirectional breadth-first search, the the search fails to find the middle vertices along the path.

Below is code for graph_vertices.txt, which includes a set of vertices I want to perform the search on.  (The vertices also have x and y coordinates, but those can be ignored for the purposes of the search.)

```
H; G; 0, 0
G; E, H; 0, 0
F; E; 421, 389
E; D, F, G; 365, 374
D; C, E; 314, 358
C; B, D; 262, 337
B; A, C; 232, 329
A; B; 0, 0
```

Here is code to parse the graph_vertices.txt file and load the vertices into a dictionary.  From there, the bidirectional breadth-first search can be performed, but it is giving an incorrect set of paths.

```
from collections import * 

class Vertex:  # Creates Vertex class.

    def __init__(self, name, adjacent, x, y):  # Instantiates Vertex object.

        self.name = name
        self.adjacent = adjacent
        self.x = int(x)
        self.y = int(y)

def bcs(start, goal):  # Defines Bidirectional Breadth-First Search function.

    forward = deque()
    backward = deque()

    backpointers_forward = {}
    backpointers_backward = {}

    # Add the starting Vertex to the queue.
    forward.append(start)
    backpointers_forward[start] = None

    backward.append(goal)
    backpointers_backward[goal] = None

    visited_forward = [start]
    visited_backward = [goal]

    # While the queue is not empty, queue and de-queue.
    while len(forward) != 0 and len(backward) != 0:

        fo = forward.popleft()

        if fo == goal or fo in backward:
            break

        for vertex_fo in fo.adjacent:

            if vertex_fo not in backpointers_forward:
                backpointers_forward[vertex_fo] = fo
                forward.append(vertex_fo)

        ba = backward.popleft()

        if ba == start or ba in forward:
            break

        for vertex_ba in ba.adjacent:

            if vertex_ba not in backpointers_backward:
                backpointers_backward[vertex_ba] = ba
                backward.append(vertex_ba)

        # Traverse through backpointers to return list of visited Vertices.

        else:

            while backpointers_forward[fo] is not None:
                visited_forward.append(fo)
                fo = backpointers_forward[fo]

            #visited_forward.append(start)

            while backpointers_backward[ba] is not None:
                visited_backward.append(ba)
                ba = backpointers_backward[ba]

            #visited_backward.append(goal)


    return visited_forward, visited_backward

def parse_line(line):

    section_split = line.split(";")

    vertex_name = section_split[0].strip()
    adjacent_vertices = section_split[1].strip().split(",")
    xy_values = section_split[2].strip().split(",")

    # add all except empty strings
    adjacent = []
    for a in adjacent_vertices:
        if a:
            adjacent.append(a.strip())

    coordinates = []
    for b in xy_values:
        if b:
            coordinates.append(b.strip())

    return vertex_name, adjacent, coordinates


# Creates a dictionary of Vertex objects from each line in the map data file.
def load_graph(data_file):

    vertex_dict = {}

    # Read the lines in the file into a list of lines:
    file_first = open(data_file, "r")

    for line in file_first:  # First pass

        # if this is a line in the correct format:
        if len(line.split(";")) == 3:
            vertex_name, adjacent_vertices, coordinates = parse_line(line)

            vertex_dict[vertex_name] = Vertex(vertex_name, [], coordinates[0], coordinates[1])

    file_first.close()

    file_second = open(data_file, "r")

    for line in file_second:

        # if this is a line in the correct format:
        if len(line.split(";")) == 3:
            vertex_name, adjacent_vertices, coordinates = parse_line(line)

            for adjacent_vertex in adjacent_vertices:

                vertex_dict[vertex_name].adjacent.append(vertex_dict[adjacent_vertex])

    file_second.close()

    return vertex_dict

dict = load_graph("graph_vertices.txt")
list1, list2 = bcs(dict["B"], dict["G"])

set1 = []
set2 = []

for entry in list1:
    set1.append(str(entry))

for entry in list2:
    set2.append(str(entry))

print(set1, set2)
```

Currently, the bidirectional BFS returns ['B', 'A', 'C'] ['G', 'E', 'H'], when it should return something like ['B', 'C', 'D] ['G', 'E', 'D'].  The A and H vertices seem to be added as if the BFS is traversing the path in the wrong direction once it reaches the middle.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you able to narrow down the problem at all? That's a lot of code to sift through.

Comment: @glibdud The only code that has an issue is in the bcs() function. The rest of the code works properly, and I included it so that anyone else could try running the same program that I am running.